# regular expression that selects all words of a string except the first 3 words

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that selects all words of a string except the first 3 words. for example a string: "Have a very nice day" should return "nice day"

Comment: Split at third whitespace?

Comment: What's your re tool? `sed`, `awk`, `perl` or others?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "words" are letters and the apostrophe (eg "can't") :

```
^([a-zA-Z']+\s+){3}(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(\w+ ){3}(.*)`

the second capture parens, `$2`, is what you want

Comment: This needs to start with `^` or it won't work.